# Change all general folder / directory icons

Tags: gnome, nautilus, icons, themes

I'm looking to change all my folder icons. This [post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/419969/any-way-to-change-the-default-folder-icon) describes something similar.

However, I want to change the default folder icon. For example, if I create a new directory, I want the folder icon to be a custom one, not the system one. And all folders (other than specific ones such as Documents, Downloads, Pictures etc) to use this custom icon.

I've also seen this [post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/99853/changing-the-default-folder-icon), which seems to be saying what I want, however I don't seem to have the folder.svg file on my machine?

Anyone able to provide some further assistance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**conversion**

You can convert your `.png` folder file to `.svg` by using this website

you can upload your image, and see the result.

[Easily Convert Bitmaps To Vectors](http://vectormagic.com/home)

But if you want to download your svg-image, you need to register. (If you register, you get 2 images for free)

If you want to convert more images then use Potrace tool from [inkscape](https://inkscape.org/en/)

*it can't convert directly from `.png` to `.svg` you first need to convert it to `.pnm` for better explanation see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16388237)

---

- Your theme's **Places** folder may not be the right location. If you can find "**folder.svg**" in there that's ok but if you can't, you should open your theme's "**index.theme**" file with **gedit** and then check its **Inheritences**'s **Places** folders. It should be in the folder named "**16**".
- When you find "**folder.svg**" as an original file, not a link, change its name as "**folder.svg.backup**" and then copy your .svg file to here and name it "**folder.svg**".
- Make a link your new "**folder.svg**", copy and paste it to all other folders in your theme's Places folder. Don't forget to make these links' names "**folder.svg**"
- When you log out and come back, your folder icon must be changed.

Comment: Thanks! I had thought it was something like this, but couldn't find the folder.svg. I eventually tracked it down to be in /usr/share/icons/Humanity/places, which isnt even the icon theme in use... Thanks for your help!